# Двойная инициализация сайта из-за img src="forum/index.php"

Tags: php

День добрый.

Ситуация такая на сайте присутствуют конструкции типа <img src="forum/index.php"> что приводит к двойной инициализации сайта грузится страница к которой обратился пользователь а потом отправляется запрос <img src="forum/index.php"> и сайт инициализируется повторно.

Скажите можно ли как то определить средствами php как пользователь загрузил страницу, через адресную строку браузера или при помощи <img src="forum/index.php">?

Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Зачем у вас там присутствуют эти конструкции?  
Проще всего добавить GET-параметр, например: `<img src="forum/index.php?init=false">`

Comment: Они не у меня, а в phpBB, он грузит аватарки/cron/captcha таким методом, я  форум интегрировал с WP и вот тут конструкции вида src="forum/index.php" дают повторные инициализацию WP